# Oracle select column as Sub query with case statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to select Column NewFlag  from a subquery in the select statement which returns Flag. When
the sub query has matching condition with the main query and Flag has result 'U' then the NewFlag 
Column should be '/U' else ''. If subquery doesn't match the main query then the NewFlag should be '/R'.

```
Create table abc (ID int,SLSID int,FLag char)

Create table master(ID int ,SLSID int)

insert into abc values(1001,123,P)
insert into abc values(1002,123,A)
insert into abc values(1003,123,U) 
insert into abc values(1004,133,U)

Insert into master (1001,123)
Insert into master (1002,123)
Insert into master (1003,123) 
Insert into master (1004,123)
```

Result should be

```
1003 123 '/U'     - since abc had matching entry in master and Flag is 'U'
1001 123 ''         - since abc had matching entry in master but Flag is not 'U'
1002 123 ''         - since abc had matching entry in master but Flag is not 'U'
1004 133 '/R'     - no matching entry for abc in master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a subselect for that. The following `OUTER JOIN` will output your desired result.

```
select master.*,
case
    when abc.id is null then '/R'
    when abc.flag = 'U' then '/U'
    else null
end flag
from master
left outer join abc on (master.id = abc.id and master.slsid = abc.slsid)
```

Note that `MASTER` is a reserved word in Oracle and you probably should not use it as a table name.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Tschernich

Answer (score 0):

Same logic as Thomas, but with inverted join to match your wanted result

```
select abc.id, abc.slsid,
case
    when master.id is null then '/R'
    when abc.flag = 'U' then '/U'
    else null
end flag
from abc
left join master on (master.id = abc.id and master.slsid = abc.slsid);
```